# Django order queryset by OnetoOneField

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a two models UserProfile and User. The UserProfile model has a onetoone filed with the user. I figured out how to order the UserProfile by a variable it contains. However, I do not know how to order the items in UserProfile by their related User models

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    full_name   = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user                = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    lunch_price         = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

I can run this query just fine:

```
from myapp.models import UserProfiles
print(UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('lunch_price')
```

I thought i'd run something like this to order by full_name, but it doesn't work

```
from myapp.models import UserProfiles
print(UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('user.full_name')
```

How do I make that jump to the user model?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can follow `OneToOneField`s and other foreign key relations by using a **double underscore (`__`)**:

```
UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('user__full_name')
```

This acts a bit similar to how in Python one usually obtains (chains of) attributes. For example if the `User` has a `OneToOneField` to (for example) an `Office` model, then we can for instance query with `user__office__floor` to sort the users by the `floor` where their office is located.

Mind that this only works given we are working with fields. So if you would for instance have a `User` class with a `first_name` and a `last_name`, and you use a `@property` for the `full_name` (in other words, the `full_name` is determined when needed), then this will not work, and you will have to sort at Python level. This is logical, since the database of course does not know anything about the Django ORM layer and hence it can not interpret what this property is doing.